# How do I send data from phone to wearable device without GoogleAPiClient?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, wearables

I'm talking about things from the phone's side. Whenever I look for a similar question I always find people using GoogleApiClient on the phone's side. This got depreciated 3 years ago, so what do I do on the phone side if I want to send an array of strings to a wearable device?

Comment: You can use either NFC, WiFi, Bluetooth, it's up to you. I find Bluetooth to be usually the best in most cases. Wifi of course is much faster and more reliable, if that's an option in your test case.

Comment: So in the case of Bluetooth the phone will be the server and the wearable is the client correct?

Comment: I did it long time ago, but I think you need to have the wearable as the server, if I remember correctly. Just try it one way and if it's not working, switch around, it's minor changes tbh

Comment: One last question what is "TAG"? I keep finding it at the developers website for log messages I keep getting it marked in red whenever I copy and paste it. Like this:  Log.e(TAG, "Socket's create() method failed", e);

Comment: TAG is any string you write in the log message that when you view the logCat to debug errors, you can filter the output to only contain the TAG you want and making debugging a lot easier. Usually, TAG is just a string of the class name. i.e for your MainActivity, the TAG will usually be "MainActivity"

Answer (score 1):

GoogleApi replaced the deprecated GoogleApiClient.

You can use the DataClient or the MessageClient depending on your requirements.
Both of them extend the new GoogleApi class.

See what you need by checking this :

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer